# Jupyter book - Change Image Size in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterbook

I am creating a jupyterbook using

```
jb build my_report --builder=pdflatex
```

In my jupyter book, my output is written in the notebooks.ipynb.

Within this report I have

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='Images/my_image.png',width=600, height=400)
```

Here the width and height have no impact when building the book. How do I change the cell metadata to change the size?

Currently the cell metadata is as follows:

```
{
    "tags": [
        "remove-input"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only (working) way at the moment is to resize the source image.

Comment: It appears this way, hopefully something that is upgraded in future versions